# My website doesn't seem right in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, web

I have created a website ([www.sebattoelisi.com](http://www.sebattoelisi.com/Urunler.aspx)) but I'm having a problem with Internet Explorer. The problem is (in Internet Explorer) when you open page for the first time, you can't see all of images and the border in DataList. Also when you click the products image page refreshes and images shows instead of go to that products page. Other browsers are fine.

I'm not natural English speaker, if I made a mistake, sorry.

Can you understand where the problem is?

Comment: Some code would help!

Comment: What version of IE are you seeing the issue with? I just tried with IE 10 with no problem. Also used compatibility mode in IE 10, which should fall back to IE 7 mode and it took a second to render the images and border, but they did render.

Comment: Same here - see no issues. Tried clearing your cache etc? Could be left-over nonsense from development.

Comment: Are you having some code inside if(IsPostBack) to load the images or bind? That would cause the image to load on PostBack when clicking a Image in DataList because of the ItemClicked event...

Comment: Thank you guys. Internet Explorer 11 causes this. Other versions (7 , 8, 9, 10) works fine. I hope they'll fix this problem. Should I notify Microsoft?

Comment: Your site is using non-ASCII characters in the querystring of the URL, which isn't standards compliant and changes the behavior of the page based on the user's client settings and configuration. You should URLEncode the components of your URLs so that it is plain ASCII (e.g. %-encoded UTF8).

Comment: If you hit F12 and use the CONSOLE tab, you can see the errors in the HTML of your website. You have a bogus DOCTYPE declaration on line 47, for instance.

Comment: Thank you EricLaw. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, but I want to show you a screenshot.

Id is a string value. As the result, when I copy and paste in other browser, it doesn't work.

I'm using Windows 7 US English only in IE10.

[image]

Mark up is like this without src in image -

```
<img id="ContentOfPage_Image1" src="" style="height:250px;width:250px;" />
```

I'm not familiar with the language. Theoretically, ID should be a number value instead of string. It is just my 2 cents.